# not able to access variable outside $.ajax method

Tags: javascript, ajax

I am trying to call the success call back function inside the jsonGet method and trying to access the variable "size " and "noOfFiles" outside the JsonGet method but it is showing undefined outside the jsonGet method.

I am using the following code

```
(function()
{
/**
 * Alfresco Slingshot aliases
 */
var $html = Alfresco.util.encodeHTML,
 $isValueSet = Alfresco.util.isValueSet;

var $html5 = Alfresco.util.encodeHTML,
$isValueSet = Alfresco.util.isValueSet;


if (Alfresco.DocumentList)
{  YAHOO.Bubbling.fire("registerRenderer",
            {
                propertyName: "FolderInfo",

               renderer: function type_renderer(record)
               {
                    var jsNode = record.jsNode;  
                    var nodeRef = jsNode.nodeRef;
                    var size, noOfFiles;

                    console.log(size);
                    console.log(Alfresco.constants.PROXY_URI + "com/acme/nodesize/node-size.json?nodeRef=" + nodeRef);

                    /*Alfresco.util.Ajax.jsonGet({*/
                        $.ajax({
                        url: encodeURI(Alfresco.constants.PROXY_URI + 'com/acme/nodesize/node-size.json?nodeRef='+nodeRef),
                        async: false,
                        successCallback:
                        {
                           fn: function loadWebscript_successCallback(response, config)
                           {
                               var obj = JSON.parse(response.serverResponse.responseText);
                               if (obj)
                               {
                                 console.log("AJAX calls works. Printing the folder size " + obj.size + " & no of files " + obj.noOfFiles);
                                   size = obj.size;
                                   noOfFiles = obj.noOfFiles;
                                   alert(size);
                                   console.log("inside success call back function");
                               }
                           },
                           /*scope: this*/
                        },
                        /*scope: this*/
                     });

                        console.log("Size"+size);
                        html5 = '<span class="item">' + "Folder Size: " + '<b>' + size + '</b>' + '</span>';
                        return html5;


               }
          });
}



})();
```

but after searching on internet,I learned that jsonGet is asynchronous,so it is exceuted after the synchronous code.so,I replaced the jsonGet method with $.ajax method and set the async to false to make $.ajax synchronous and access the variable outside the jsonGet method.but,still the variables "size" is undefined.

any help would be greatly appreciated.I am trying dis from many days

Comment: You definitely *don't* want to use `async: false`.  (I wouldn't be surprised if any given browser simply stops supporting it.)  Whatever operations you want to perform in response to the asynchronous operation should be performed by or invoked by your callback.

Comment: $.ajax is asynchronous too, in javascript most functions are.

Solutions :
 - Use a Promise either with bluebird or ES6
 - use ES8 and make the function `await`
. I don't know if the `async:false` option even still works